# Carbon Assignment to Variable not Passed

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I've set up two date pickers in a view; one for start date and one for end date.
The request is passed to a controller index method where it interacts with this `if` block.

If I set a start date, e.g. the `1st of April`, I expect:

- `$start_date == 2017-04-01 00:00:00`
- `$end_date == 2017-04-08 00:00:00` ( A week later)

But when I run a `dd($start_time.' '.$end_time)` after the block, it returns

- `2017-04-08 00:00:00 2017-04-08 00:00:00`

```php
    // If start or end date is not passed, set the bookings to view the upcoming week
    if (isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
        $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
        if ($start_date->diffInDays($end_date, false) < 1 )
        {
            return redirect()->route('bookings.index')->with('errors', 'Please choose an end date <strong>after</strong> start date!');
        }

    }
    else if (isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
        $end_date = $start_date->addWeek();
    }
    else if (isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
        $start_date = ($end_date->subWeek());
    }
    else
    {
        $start_date = Carbon::now();
        $end_date = Carbon::now()->addweek();
    }
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: A debugging tip would be to echo start_date and end_date after each assignment. See where the value changes erroneously

Comment: To clarify, I'm triggering the first `else if` statement, so it is only two assignments occurring over two lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code arises because **Carbon objects are mutable**.

It basically means when you do `$end_date = $start_date->addWeek();` both `start_date` and `end_date` are same objects.

So you can `clone` the `start_date` to `end_date` and then call methods on it.

*The solution should be*

```
   // If start or end date is not passed, set the bookings to view the upcoming week
    if (isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
        $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
        if ($start_date->diffInDays($end_date, false) < 1 )
        {
            return redirect()->route('bookings.index')->with('errors', 'Please choose an end date <strong>after</strong> start date!');
        }

    }
    else if (isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
        $end_date = clone $start_date;
        $end_date = $end_date->addWeek();
    }
    else if (isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date);
        $start_date= clone $end_date;
        $start_date= $start_date->subWeek();
    }
    else
    {
        $start_date = Carbon::now();
        $end_date = Carbon::now()->addweek();
    }
```